# `angular` how to fix this warning `Emitted value instead of an instance of Error`

Tags: angular, angular-cli

My `angular CLI` works fine. getting the images as well. But still, I am getting a `warning` like this:

```
WARNING in ./src/app/home/home.component.css
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-url: C:\Projects\dhl-testing\src\app\home\home.component.css:4:3: Can't read file 'C:\Projects\dhl-testing\src\app\home\assets\images\dhlmoped.jpg', ignoring
```

and

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./src/styles.css
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-url: C:\Projects\dhl-testing\src\assets\css\sm\header.css:43:5: Can't read file 'C:\Projects\dhl-testing\src\assets\css\sm\assets\images\icon-user.png', ignoring
```

what are these warnings and how to fix them?

Comment: @ user2024080 , Can you share the solution you got for this question?

Comment: HI, i am also facing same error. i want to use releative path but if i use build getting failed. any solution available for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add '/' to the beginning of the path:
example:'/assets/images/logo.png' where assets is located in the root under src Folder

Comment: It's not an answer!! If you use custom base bath / deply path, slash will destroy your url resolving.

Comment: you only need to add it to  "background: url(/assets/);" property

Answer (score 0):

In `webpack.config.json`, do the following change:

```
"exclude": [
      // instead of /\/node_modules\//
      path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')
    ]
```

That regex is not working properly for some reason.

*(At least, this was my issue...)*

Comment: Under `angular-cli` at where the file would be? I am not able to get the file you mentioned

Answer (score -1):

From the looks of it, you are using absolute CSS image paths

```
C:\Projects\dhl-testing\src\app\home\assets\images\dhlmoped.jpg
```

Make this relative, something like

```
url("\assets\images\dhlmoped.jpg")
```

Comment: The specified answer is not a relative url. Adding '/' to the beginning makes it an absolute url.